# Reflect set color, not actual scene

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I have a glossy object in a scene. I want to have this glossy object render as if it were inside a pure white environment, and not reflect the actual scene around it. However, I still want it in the scene so that other objects will reflect it.

Is this possible? I am guessing it can be done if I render the object on its own layer within a pure white sphere or something similar. Is it possible without creating a separate layer/scene? Can I do it within the material?

Comment: The easiest way would be to just put it on another layer. You maybe also can do something with material settings. If you get the system behind layers once, its pretty easy. So i would recommend going that way.

Comment: Yeah. I'm trying to find another option so that I can avoid having to render a separate layer. It'll add a bunch of render time.

Comment: Maybe related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15227/ibl-with-cycles-can-i-use-a-different-background-image-from-the-one-that-affect

Comment: Could you just bake it while in the pure white environment and then apply as a texture to an emission shader?

Comment: @RichSedman that would technically work, but it would then cause VRAM issues when GPU rendering, and would be a hassle.

Comment: Also wouldnt even look close as good