# How do i keep HDR background without having to see it when rendering?

Tags: hdri

Can anyone tell me how to maintain HDR as a background light source, without seeing it through the rendered room window?

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56070/cycles-envirement-background-for-lighting-different-then-render-background and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49337/how-to-use-multiple-hdris

Comment: Also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15227/ibl-with-cycles-can-i-use-a-different-background-image-from-the-one-that-affect

Comment: Out of curiosity, why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cycles: envirement background for lighting different then render background](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56070/cycles-envirement-background-for-lighting-different-then-render-background) or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49337/how-to-use-multiple-hdris/49403#49403

Answer (score 0):

Select **Render** Tab in properties view & in **FILM** section, check **Transparent**.
However, The reflections of HDR will show up.

[image]